How get total in an array of object
I have this array, and i want to get the sum amount of each Order.item
[
{"OrderReceiverId":"6698eea782e24cc9d42eab7f",
"Order":{
 "CustomerId":"669aa55079cce2e96f9a7e69",
"CustomerName":"Erigbemi",
"Date":"2024/07/19",
"TrackingId":"43035",
"Status":"Processing",
"Amount":{"$numberInt":"25000"},
"Item":"Orange"
 }
}, {"OrderReceiverId":"6698eea782e24cc9d42eab7f",
"Order":{
 "CustomerId":"669aa55079cce2e96f96t77",
"CustomerName":"James",
"Date":"2024/07/19",
"TrackingId":"42335",
"Status":"Processing",
"Amount":{"$numberInt":"15000"},
"Item":"Tomatoes"
 }, {"OrderReceiverId":"6698eea782e24cc9d42eab7f",
"Order":{
 "CustomerId":"669aa55079cce2e96f9a7e69",
"CustomerName":"Erigbemi",
"Date":"2024/07/19",
"TrackingId":"22235",
"Status":"Processing",
"Amount":{"$numberInt":"15000"},
"Item":"Tomatoes"
 }
]

How do i get the total of each "Item", something like this
"Rice": 30000
"Tomatoes": 15000
i tried this
let itm = {};

            sellingInfo.forEach(order => {
                const item = order.Order.Item;
                const amt = order.Order.Amount;
                
                if(!itm[item]){
                    itm[item] = amt;
                }
                itm[item] += amt;
            })

            res.json(itm);

But i seemd to be getting the wrong out put, this is what I get
{
"Orange": 50000,
"Tomatoes": 45000
}

It would help if your example output could be derived from the example JSON input. Besides that, you need to [edit] the question and show us what you tried, so we can improve on that or explain where you went wrong.

made modifications to it

figured it out, I made amends to the loop, by adding the else block, that worked for  me, thanks

you may use Array.reduce() method


const data = 
  [ { OrderReceiverId: '6698eea782e24cc9d42eab7f'
    , Order: 
      { CustomerId   : '669aa55079cce2e96f9a7e69'
      , CustomerName : 'Erigbemi'
      , Date         : '2024/07/19'
      , TrackingId   : '43035'
      , Status       : 'Processing'
      , Amount       : { $numberInt: '25000' } 
      , Item         : 'Orange'
    } } 
  , { OrderReceiverId: '6698eea782e24cc9d42eab7f'
    , Order: 
      { CustomerId   : '669aa55079cce2e96f96t77'
      , CustomerName : 'James'
      , Date         : '2024/07/19'
      , TrackingId   : '42335'
      , Status       : 'Processing'
      , Amount       : { $numberInt: '20000' } 
      , Item         : 'Rice'
    } } 
  , { OrderReceiverId: '6698eea782e24cc9d42eab7f'
    , Order: 
      { CustomerId   : '669aa55079cce2e96f9a7e69'
      , CustomerName : 'Erigbemi'
      , Date         : '2024/07/19'
      , TrackingId   : '22235'
      , Status       : 'Processing'
      , Amount       : { $numberInt: '12000' } 
      , Item         : 'Rice'
    } } 
  ];
  
const Sums = data.reduce( (r,{Order}) => 
  {
  r[Order.Item] ??= 0;
  r[Order.Item] += +Order.Amount.$numberInt;
  return r;
  },{});

console.log( Sums );
.as-console-wrapper{max-height:100% !important;top:0}
.as-console-row::after{display:none !important;}




You can use reduce method to accumulate the total amounts for each item:


const data = [
    {
        "OrderReceiverId": "6698eea782e24cc9d42eab7f",
        "Order": {
            "CustomerId": "669aa55079cce2e96f9a7e69",
            "CustomerName": "Erigbemi",
            "Date": "2024/07/19",
            "TrackingId": "43035",
            "Status": "Processing",
            "Amount": {"$numberInt": "25000"},
            "Item": "Orange"
        }
    },
    {
        "OrderReceiverId": "6698eea782e24cc9d42eab7f",
        "Order": {
            "CustomerId": "669aa55079cce2e96f96t77",
            "CustomerName": "James",
            "Date": "2024/07/19",
            "TrackingId": "42335",
            "Status": "Processing",
            "Amount": {"$numberInt": "20000"},
            "Item": "Rice"
        }
    },
    {
        "OrderReceiverId": "6698eea782e24cc9d42eab7f",
        "Order": {
            "CustomerId": "669aa55079cce2e96f9a7e69",
            "CustomerName": "Erigbemi",
            "Date": "2024/07/19",
            "TrackingId": "22235",
            "Status": "Processing",
            "Amount": {"$numberInt": "12000"},
            "Item": "Rice"
        }
    }
];

const totals = data.reduce((acc, entry) => {
    const order = entry.Order;
    const item = order.Item;
    const amount = parseInt(order.Amount.$numberInt, 10);

    if (acc[item]) {
        acc[item] += amount;
    } else {
        acc[item] = amount;
    }

    return acc;
}, {});

console.log(totals);



